# OUTPUT TO FILE LOCAL SYBASE IQ 16

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I'm trying to write my existing tables to files and save it locally.

I'm using T-SQL with SQuirrel JDBC Connection to Sybase

I tried the following Code to write results into a file:

```
SELECT * FROM date_dimension; 
OUTPUT TO "C:\Users\temp\output.txt" FORMAT ASCII;
```

I dont know why it doesn't work but I get a Syntax error while trying this.

> Error: SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'OUTPUT' on line 1
>   SQLState:  42W04
>   ErrorCode: 102

Can someone see a mistake in the code? Is there another way to write into file from Sybase IQ?

I'm new to all this Tools and I'm sry for such a question

Please help me :)

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_DIMENSION
(   [DateKey] INT primary key, 
    [Date] DATETIME,
    [FullDateUK] CHAR(10), -- Date in dd-MM-yyyy format
    [FullDateUSA] CHAR(10),-- Date in MM-dd-yyyy format
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work, your syntax is correct, can you provide the ddl of the table?

Edit: try this select statement:

select DateKey,("Date"),FullDateUK,FullDateUSA from DATE_DIMENSION;
OUTPUT TO "C:\Users\temp\output.txt" FORMAT ASCII;

Comment: I think i can't even use Output to in t-SQL after my researchs

Comment: Your research is false, im using sybase-iq and i had no problem to write the output file. Just post the structure of your table (DDL), then maybe i can help you.

Comment: i have added an example to my question. Maybe you are using ISQL to Output file?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, my bad, i was using isql, but if you used a keyword (such as DATE) for a column name, try enclosing the keyword in quotation marks ("DATE"),or just try to rename the column and see if that solves your problem, hope that works. Cheers

Comment: Yeah I know :) I try to find an colleague who has Access via ISQL thx for your help

Comment: are your Output to Statements are saved Server-side ?

Comment: You dont need to find an colleague, just try first with the select statement where you put ("Date"), if that doesnt work, then try to find an colleague with isql access. I save the file from the iq-server on my pc, so i would say it is local.